# Entity framework distinct but not on all columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'd like to make a query through entity framework that unions contacts from two different tables, remove duplicates and orders by date. The issue I'm having is around the different dates making the same contact appear as unique. I don't want to include the date in the distinct but I do need it afterwards for the ordering. I can't do the ordering first, remove the date and then perform the distinct, because the distinct changes the ordering. Neither can I order before the union because that doesn't ensure ordering after the union.

I would like to distinct all fields except the date, which is only required for the ordering.

Ideally I would pass a comparer to the distinct but EF can't translate this to SQL.

```
db.Packages.Select(p => new Recent()
{
    Name = p.Attention, Address1 = p.Address1, ... , Date = ShippingDate
})
.Concat(db.Letters.Select(l => new Recent()
{
    Name = l.AddressedTo, Address1 = p.Address1, ..., Date = MarkedDate
})
.Distinct()
.OrderByDescending(r => r.Date);
```

OR the problem in SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT Attention, Address1, ShippingDate
FROM Packages
UNION ALL
SELECT AddressedTo, Address1, MarkedDate
FROM Letters
ORDER BY ShipmentDate DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a GroupBy to do what you want, like so (not to mention [Group By is more performant than Distinct in EF](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/546/using-grouping-instead-of-distinct-in-entity-framework-to-optimize-performance)):

```
db.Packages.Select(p => new Recent()
{
    Name = p.Attention, Address1 = p.Address1, ... , Date = ShippingDate})
.Concat(db.Letters.Select(l => new Recent()
{
    Name = l.AddressedTo, Address1 = p.Address1, ..., Date = MarkedDate}))
.GroupBy(p => <parameters to group by - which make the record distinct>)
.Select(g => new {Contact = g.Key, LastShippingDate = g.Max(p => p.ShippingDate)});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd be concerned with this approach, even if it was possible distinct would then remove one of the items and leave you with random date out of the two, and then your sort would be totally unpredictable.